# If $f \in C^2$ such that $ f \ge f'' \ge 0,\, f'\ge 0$, prove that $f \ge f'$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I don't see the trick to this question

> Let $f \in C^2(R)$ such that $
> f \ge f'' \ge 0,\, f'\ge 0$. Show that $f \ge f'$.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang yes in $R^2$

Comment: @ShengtongZhang Even on $[0, \infty)$ your example doesn't satisfy $f \ge f''$.

Comment: Sorry for the false comment. Could you show your own attempts?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g = f' / f$. Then
$$g' = \frac{ff'' - f'^2}{f^2}\leq 1 - g^2.$$
So if $h(x) = g(-x)$, then
$$h' \geq h^2 - 1.$$
Suppose the contrary, and $h(a) > 1$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the observation is $h$ will blowup in finite time, contradiction. So $h \leq 1$ everywhere.

Comment: Nice answer, although a few more details regarding the finite time blow-up would certainly be helpful.

Comment: Could you add more details to the blowup observation please?